# How to find currently streaming file in ffmpeg stream that uses a file list

Tags: python, bash, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to stream to an RTMP server. I am using the option to provide ffmpeg a text file with a list of files to stream. My file looks like this:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'stream_file1.flv'
file 'stream_file2.flv'
file 'stream_file3.flv'
```

It loops through these files while streaming. Is there a way to programmatically find out when ffmpeg switches between each file? Either from ffmpeg dumping some logs that I can injest, or by using python to check the state of the stream every second?

Comment: you want to do something after every file??

Comment: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Comment: correct. when ffmpeg starts streaming the next file I would like to know about that event in some way. specifically knowing which file it's on would be beest.

Comment: `inotifywait -m -r -e OPEN --format '%f' /path/to/videos`  - that's assuming that you don't have other processes reading from that directory structure at the same time.

Comment: @DigitalDisaster - no reaction in 9 days?  Can't have been too important ... =}

Comment: Some disasters have occurred and the priority of this has been lowered. But I will come back to test these methods eventually. Thank you for you time and insights.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-loglevel debug` to your `ffmpeg` command and parse the console output for lines such as:

```
[NULL @ 0x559e278d8a40] Opening 'stream_file2.flv' for reading
```